# how to get two kinds of components structure in single react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

i have a react app in which i want that if user route start with admin it should have a different navbar

lets take example

normal page

```
<NormalNavbar/>

<NormalHeader/>
<NormalBody/>
<NormalFooter/>
```

But if i have the admin route
then i want to have

```
<AdminNavbar/>
<AdminHeader/>
<AdminBody/>
<AdminFooter/>
```

The issue is when we wind it inside the Routes then we decide the normal components which are loading i will paste the example below

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route exact path="/product/:id" element={<ProductPage />} />
          <Route exact path="sarangAdmin/create-product" element={<CreateProduct />} />
          <Route exact path="login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route exact path="profile" element={<Profile />} />
          <Route exact path="register" element={<Register />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </>
    </div>
  );
```

You can see my current navbar and footer going to be same

Comment: if you want to make many elements to change on admin from normal page try to use ternary statement with 2 different page as normal page/ admin page before calling url. else pass usertype as props in route and hanlde it one page like props.userType === 'admin'  ? <adminDiv /> : <normalDiv/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the above answers is good but its not the optimal solution I wanted so I get the solution by looking other git repository [here is the repository](https://github.com/jgudo/ecommerce-react)  that shows how you should do it in a perfect way make route component structure and then you can render them conditionally which I wanted in my case the most optimum solution to my question

Answer (score 1):

you can put elements with conditions like that

```
{isAdmin? <AdminNavbar> : <NormalNavbar> }
```

OR

in the navbar component view different menu